# SetInterval to AutoClick in menu

Tags: jquery, click, setinterval

I have the following structure...

```
<div id="displaySlider">
  <div class="slideItem" id="idA">....</div>
  <div class="slideItem" id="idB">....</div>
  <div class="slideItem" id="idC">....</div>
  <div class="slideItem" id="idD">....</div>
</div>
<ul id="menuSlider">
  <li><a href="#" rel="pintor"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="pedreiro"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="marceneiro"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="gesseiro"></a></li>
</ul>
```

When the page load I click in first item. 
`$('#menuSlider li a:first').trigger('click');`

I need to create a jquery for every X seconds click the next item and return to the last first.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
var links = $('#menuSlider a');
var currentIndex = -1;

var click = function() {
    currentIndex++;

    if (links.length == currentIndex) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    $(links[currentIndex]).trigger('click');
    console.log(links[currentIndex]);
};

if (links.length) {
    setInterval(click, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
It's exactly that.
I made a small change to stop the transition when the mouse is over the area of ​​the Slider:

```
var links = $('#menuSlider a');
var currentIndex = -1;  
var click = function() {
    currentIndex++;

    if (links.length == currentIndex) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
    $(links[currentIndex]).trigger('click');
    console.log(links[currentIndex]);
};
if (links.length) {
    interval = setInterval(click, 2000);
}
$('#wrapSlider').hover(function() {
    interval = clearInterval(interval);
}, function() {
    interval = setInterval(click, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Hey Danilo, since you're new here I'll give a few tips. In cases like this please mark the answer as correct and give your consideration on how to improve the answer on comments. You should not duplicate an answer like that, and you should avoid answering your own questions when there are valid answers.